# textbox focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, focus

I need to focus out from the textbox when it focus in.

I try to set focus for outer div and its working fine in IE but not in mozilla.

How do I do this?

This is my current code:

```
<div id="outer"> <input type = "textbox" /></div> Onfocus: document.getElementById("outer").focus()
```

Comment: Any code from your side?

Comment: <div id="outer">
<input type = "textbox" /></div>

Onfoucs:

document.getElementById("outer").focus()

Comment: Please put this into your question.

Comment: all the answer are not focus out from the text box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried all the answers and not worked in all the browsers. And I combined all together in to it.

1. `TextBox.readonly = true;`

**OnFocus:**

2. `var curText = TextBox.value;`
   `TextBox.value = "";`
   `TextBox.value = curText;`
3. `TextBox.blur();`
4. `TextBox_Parent.focus()`

And its working fine in all the browsers

Answer (score 6):

I wonder what's the purpose of using a textbox in this case if the user can never write anything inside. Just add a `disabled="disabled"` attribute or `readonly="readonly"` (in case you want to post the value).

Answer (score 6):

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" />
```

In JS:

```
document.getElementById("input1").onfocus = function () { this.blur(); }
```

Some elements cannot accept focus without being editable.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the point in that? JS would be (didn't test it):

```
$('#textbox').focusin(function() {
   $(this).focusout();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/*for textarea*/
$(document).ready(function() {
$('textarea[type="text"]').addClass("idleField");
$('textarea[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
        this.value = '';
    }
    if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
        this.select();
    }
});
$('textarea[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");
    if ($.trim(this.value == '')){
        this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
    }
});
```

});

**that's what I used on my form.**

Comment: This code includes JQuery. The question is about vanilla javascript.